# How to store Font information in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, fonts

I am working on a Windows Application implemented in C#. One of the requirements is for the user to be able to select a set of fonts and save them into a database. Among the information that I need to store for the font are:

- The name of the font
- Size
- Whether its bold, italic, underline

So far I have this information stored as separate fields in the database. Latter I build the Font object from this information. However, i find it impossible to create a new object with all the needed settings (e.g., a font that is both bold and italic).

To illustrate I do something like this (note that I work with EF, so the methods are just for illustration):

```
string font_name = GetFontNameFromDatabase();
string font_size = GetFontSizeFromDatabase();
...

Font f = new Font(font_name, font_size);
```

My question is whether there is a convenient way to store the font object in SLQ Server Database. Maybe as a binary field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`FontConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontconverter.aspx) class to serialize and deserialize your fonts:

```
var fc = new FontConverter();   
Font f1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);  
var fontAsString = fc.ConvertToInvariantString(f1); // "Times New Roman, 12pt"
Font f2 = (Font)fc.ConvertFromInvariantString(fontAsString);
Console.WriteLine(f2.ToString());   // [Font: Name=Times New Roman, Size=12, ...]
```